# Netbeans java - cannot append StringBuffer to jtextfield

Tags: netbeans

when i try to append a text to the jtextfield it doesn't work :(
  here is my code:

```
try{
           jLabel9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/slike/1.png")));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/src/datoteke/besede.txt"));
            String vrstica;
            String nakljucno;
            vrstica = in.readLine();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(vrstica);
            jTextField1.append(sb);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
```

[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCG1m.png)

First I tried to use

```
jTextfield1.setText(vrstica)
```

but it isn't displaying anything to `jTextField`

Then I tried to use 
    jTextField1.append(vrstica)

and it shows me this error:

> cannot find symbol Symbol: method append(String) Location: variable
>   jTextField1 of type jTextField

..... this is the error it shows me on line where i typed: jTextField1.append(vrstica).... hope you understand me

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Short version - Saying it doesn't work isn't much help. If you can explain how it doesn't work, Either showing what errors you get and where, or what behaviour you're expecting and what you're getting, that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: ok, so first i tried to use jTextfield1.setText(vrstica) method, but it isn't displaying anything to jTextField... then i tried to use jTextField1.append(vrstica) and it shows me this error: cannot find symbol      Symbol: method append(String) Location: variable jTextField1 of type jTextField..... this is the error it shows me on line where i typed: jTextField1.append(vrstica).... hope you understand me

Comment: If you edit your question and post your information there - it will be easier to spot it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must change from

`jTextField1.append(sb);`

to this

`jTextField1.setText(sb.toString());`